# How to display a Google Static Map in Android Textview

Tags: java, android, textview, google-maps-static-api

I have a TextView in an ExpandableList and I am setting the TextView's text through `Html.fromHtml()`. I am trying to display a [Static Google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Sensor) in the Textview and have it act as a button. Here is the link of a sample Google Static Map snippet that I'd like to include...

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386052,-122.083851&zoom=13&markers=size:mid|color:blue|37.386052,-122.083851&path=color:0x0000FF80|weight:5|37.40276,-122.06360&size=220x150&sensor=false

Here is how I'm trying to do it. Notice me trying to display the image at the end of `infoString`

```
String infoString = ("<img src='map.png'><b> Address: </b>" + address + ", Boston, MA 02210<br />" +
    "<img src='star.png'><b> Rating: </b>" + rating + " out of 5" + "<br />" +
    "<img src='phone.png'><b> Phone: </b> <a href=\"tel:" + phoneDial +"\">" + phoneDisplay + "</a>" + "<br />" +
    "<img src='yelp.png'><b> Yelp: </b> <a href=\"" + url + "\">Click Here</a> <br />" + 
    "<a href='mailto:nomail@mail.com'><img src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386052,-122.083851&zoom=13&markers=size:mid|color:blue|37.386052,-122.083851&path=color:0x0000FF80|weight:5|37.40276,-122.06360&size=220x150&sensor=false'/></a>");

businessInfo.add(Html.fromHtml(infoString, new ImageGetter(), null));
```

This obviously doesn't work and just shows a blue box instead of the image. As for the other images in the `infoString`, I am using an ImageGetter to show those. The ImageGetter works fine but I obviously cannot use it on a static map because the URL of the map will be changing depending on the address that gets put in.

Can someone share a solution that will allow me to show the Static Map in my Textview?

Comment: why wouldn't you use an imageview since it is an `Image`?

Comment: @tyczj I've though about that, but how do I grab an image from a link that doesn't end with a picture file extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can show the image form this static map url just use Glide, Picasso or any other image loading library to download the image from the url and show it in your imageview